# Subclass set-method not working

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class RectangleEx extends Rectangle
{
    int height =0;
    int width=0;

    public RectangleEx(int height, int width)
    {
        super(height,width);
    }

    public RectangleEx()
    {
        super(0,0);
        this.setHeight(5);
        System.out.println(this.height);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why, when creating a new RectangleEx using the second constructor, its height is 0 and not 5? This is the code for setHeight in the superclass:

```
public void setHeight(int height)
{
    this.height = height;
}
```

Comment: The `height` from the super-class is not the same than the one from your inherited class.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to instance variable hiding. Since you have declared another variable `height` with the same name in the sub-class, it hides the one that is defined in the super class. So, when you access the variable, using `this.height`, that will give you the value of `height` defined in the sub class, which you haven't set at all.

The call:

```
this.setHeight(5);
```

invokes the method of super class, which sets height in super class itself, whereas

```
System.out.println(this.height);
```

is accessing the `height` defined in `RectangleEx` rather than `Rectangle`, which is still 0.

If you want to access the `height` of super class, define a *getter* in super class, which will return the super class variable.

Comment: @damo. I don't think that works that way. Member hiding is not even considered in case of private variables, because they won't even be visible outside the class. Hiding applies to public, protected or package-private variables.

Comment: Wait... when I do this.setHeight(5), I'm setting height of the SUPERCLASS to 5? But I haven't even defined an object belonging to the superclass! I'm very confused. I thought objects of the subclass inherited the set methods and the subclass objects could refer to themselves with this.method...

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist. If you have defined `setHeight` method in super class and not in subclass then only this works. Because then subclass method will be called.

Comment: But which object am I setting the height for by using this.setHeight() here? This object doesn't seem to exist!

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist. Where have you defined `setHeight` method? If it is only defined in super class, then the super class method will be called. If you have overridden the `setHeight` method in subclass, then subclass method will be called.

Comment: @RohitJain This is what I meant: http://ideone.com/1UdI2n (although I would never recommend doing anything like this)

Comment: "But I haven't even defined an object belonging to the superclass!" Yes, you have.  The object of the subclass also belongs to the superclass - it contains everything that is defined in either class.

Comment: So I always need to override the superclass setHeight method in order to use it for the subclass?

Comment: I think you should visit a good Java tutorial, regarding Method Overriding, and member hiding. It would be difficult to explain everthing in comments.

Comment: @damo. Ok. There you are explicitly accessing super class variable using `super` keyword. So, member hiding is not applicable there.